# how to send data from extjs controller to jsp page

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have initialized some variables in the Extjs controller. When I click on a row of a grid then values of some attribute will be displayed. Below code is working fine if I want to display in console. but i want to send the variables in another jsp page page.
this is my controller...

```
selectionchange : function(){
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('lineGridChart');
    var selectedRecords= grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    myWTN  = selectedRecords[0].get('wtn');
    myMOU  = selectedRecords[0].get('avg');
    myWING = selectedRecords[0].get('wing');
    myPDU  = selectedRecords[0].get('pdu');

},
```

I want to send the values of the variables to the jsp page... please help..

Answer (score 0):

One way is setting a cookie and passing the value from one page to another. Another way is to call a servlet using an ajax request and forwarding from the servlet to the jsp. In the ajax request, you can set parameters and pass them.

Comment: you can but before calling you need to set a cookie or something to call the jsp. JSP is nothing but a servlet once it compiles, so it should work either way.